# Ubuntu hangs - Need hard reboot

Tags: 14.04, networking, 16.04, hardware, bug-reporting

## System details:

[image]

---

## Installation history:

> Installed 14.04 ubuntu LTS from CD and got upgraded to 16.04 LTS using software update.
>
> Laptop is dual boot with windows7 & Ubuntu

---

## Observation:

> ***Interesting observation is***, if Windows/Linux OS is working under high bandwidth wifi coverage, then windows/Linux continue working properly(for ever). Under low bandwidth wifi coverage Windows/Linux hang within 5 minutes.
>
> That means, Ubuntu/Windows7 works for properly(for ever), until, until some application/browser connects to Internet thru wifi.
>
> `mohet01@mohet01-ubuntu:~$lspci -knn | grep Net
>       02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
>       Subsystem: Dell QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [1028:020c]`
>
> Windows 7 & Ubuntu are experiencing similar hang problem.
>
> All connected applications hang and ubuntu gets hanged. Need to hard reboot ubuntu.
>
> Ubuntu is set to PST time where as the laptop is located in EST
>
> Below error pattern is shown all time in `/var/log/syslog`

/****************************************************************************/

```
Mar 11 08:01:09 mohet01-ubuntu kernel: [  320.383424] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
Mar 11 08:01:09 mohet01-ubuntu kernel: [  320.383431] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
Mar 11 08:01:09 mohet01-ubuntu kernel: [  320.393976] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
         ...........
Mar 11 08:01:12 mohet01-ubuntu NetworkManager[946]: <warn>  [1489248072.6608] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Mar 11 08:01:12 mohet01-ubuntu NetworkManager[946]: <info>  [1489248072.6609] device (wlan0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found') [50 120 53]
Mar 11 08:01:12 mohet01-ubuntu NetworkManager[946]: <info>  [1489248072.6611] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Mar 11 08:01:12 mohet01-ubuntu NetworkManager[946]: <warn>  [1489248072.6616] device (wlan0): Activation: failed for connection 'Toronto Public Library'
Mar 11 08:01:12 mohet01-ubuntu NetworkManager[946]: <info>  [1489248072.6624] device (wlan0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Mar 11 08:01:12 mohet01-ubuntu kernel: [  323.996216] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Mar 11 08:01:12 mohet01-ubuntu NetworkManager[946]: <info>  [1489248072.6649] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Mar 11 08:01:12 mohet01-ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1218]: wlan0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Mar 11 08:01:12 mohet01-ubuntu kernel: [  324.141569] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
Mar 11 08:01:12 mohet01-ubuntu kernel: [  324.141575] ath: phy0: Unable to reset channel, reset status -22
Mar 11 08:01:12 mohet01-ubuntu kernel: [  324.152109] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
```

> `/var/log/faillog` has no information except `^@^@`

---

---

**Question:**

Is it something to do with hardware issue?

or

Is it something to do with WIFI driver issue in both(Linux/Windows7) that triggers this problem?